# Pulling information from a Listbox and pulling it into a combobox - all using SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox, listbox

Edit: as requested here is the XAML code for the listbox/comboboxs - driver/product/vehicle and also the textbox used for a weigh.

```
<ListBox Name="WeighBox" Height="176" SelectionChanged="WeighBox_SelectionChanged"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="selDriver" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405"/>
<ComboBox Name="selVehicle" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405"/>
<ComboBox Name="selProduct" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405"/>
<TextBox Name="weigh1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,184.334,-0.667"></TextBox>
```

I have been trying to figure this out all night without any success. I am not sure I am going about the problem the correct way but here we go.

I have 3 combobox's each pulling information from 3 DB tables and a save button that saves the information into another DB table. My listbox shows 1 of the column from the saved to table. I want to be able to select the listbox and then it fills my comboboxs with the fields.

https://recordit.co/z76BIBByPi a video of what I currently have to give a better idea. I can not explain this stuff to save my life.

I tried the fallowing thinking there could be some way to import the information in to each text box. Each one gives their own type of error. In my mind I am going about this the wrong way but I don't know the correct way to implement it.

```
wreg = selVehicle.SelectedItem.ToString();
wreg = selVehicle.SelectedItem.ToString();
wreg = selVehicle.ItemsSource.ToString();
weigh1.Text = wreg;
selDriver.Text = wdriver;
selProduct.Text = wproduct;
weigh1.Text = wweight;
selVehicle.Text = wreg;
wreg = selVehicle.ItemsSource.ToString();
selVehicle.Items.Add(wreg);
```

This is my listbox (and fill) where I am trying to pull my info from

```
private void WeighBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.dbPath);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from weighings where w_vehicle='" + WeighBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ", con); 

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int _weighid = dr.GetInt32(0);
                string wreg = dr.GetString(16);
                string wdriver = dr.GetString(13);
                string wproduct = dr.GetString(11);
                int wweight = dr.GetInt32(3);

                selDriver.SelectedItem.Equals(wdriver);// = wdriver;
                selProduct.SelectedItem = wproduct;
                selVehicle.SelectedItem = wreg;
                weigh1.Text = wreg;
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

public void FillListbox()
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.dbPath);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from weighings where w_status = 'Pending'", con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string wreg = dr.GetString(16);
                string wdriver = dr.GetString(13);
                string wproduct = dr.GetString(11);
                int wweight = dr.GetInt32(3);
                WeighBox.Items.Add(wreg);
                selVehicle.Text = wreg;
                selDriver.Text = wdriver;
                selProduct.Text = wproduct;
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

This is one of my comboboxes, you can imagine they are the same.

```
public void FillDriverComboBox()
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.dbPath);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from drivers", con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            selDriver.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            selDriver.DisplayMemberPath = "driver_name";
            selDriver.SelectedValuePath = "driver_id";

            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I expect when I click on a item in my listbox it fills my combobox and any textboxes I want. I can fill my textboxes OK but its the comboboxes I really want to fill. I could make more textboxes to fill my info but I want to make my fields be able to update in the future. Best fix the problem now.

Comment: Please add the XAML too, so when can understand which is which.

Comment: I have added the XAML for the listbox/comboboxs/textbox. If there is anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill your comboboxes according to the selected item of your listbox then at first you should fill the listbox. After that, add a mouseclick event method to get the item value and also write the code to fill the comboboxes on that same function.

Comment: All my combobox's are filled already from the SQL table each one pulls from. The problem is I am trying to select from the listbox to then fill(or use not sure how to say it) the comboboxs.

Comment: Let me get that scenario first. Suppose, you have all the registration numbers in that list box. When you click a registration from the box the combo boxes will automatically select the driver, vehicle and all other items that has been assigned to that registration number. Am i getting this?

Comment: 100% what I am after yes

Comment: I guess your listbox is not getting the data from database.

Comment: in your sql command "WeighBox.SelectedItem.ToString()" you should specify the "value" or the "text" from SelectedItem object. For example, SelectedItem.Text.ToString() or SelectedItem.Value.ToString().

Comment: I think I have tried that already. I get the same object error. `wreg = selVehicle.SelectedValue.ToString();` / = `selVehicle.SelectedValue.ToString(wreg);` / `selVehicle.SelectedValue.ToString(16);`